# How to make Unity 2D dash background blurry transparent using QT code?

Tags: development, unity-2d, qt

How to make Unity 2D dash background blurry transparent using QT code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the QGraphicsBlurEffect QML element applied to the background image in the dash (GnomeBackground.qml): http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7.1/qgraphicsblureffect.html

However this will not make the elements behind the dash blurry when using compositing (when the dash is truly transparent). That will require cooperation of the window manager.